# make Kinetic use my existing canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I’ve got an existing html5 canvas whiteboard.
how can I make Kinetic use my existing canvas to add some of it's functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new layer like this:

```
var whiteboardLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

and access the generated canvas element like this:

```
var canvas = whiteboardLayer.getCanvas().getElement();
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answer's the OP's question. How do you make a kinetic.js Scene use an existing canvas instead of passing in a container id? Forgive me if I am misunderstanding something.