# Make kineticjs use existing canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I am attempting to use [kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/) with an existing canvas. The problem is that the kinetic.js API requires that you specify the id of the container element and then kinetic.js creates a `Kinetic.Stage` (which creates and uses its own canvas).

For instance:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 239,
    y: 75,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(rect);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
</script>
```

I want to be able to use an existing canvas element with kinetic.js instead of it creating its own. Is this possible?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135582/make-kinetic-use-my-existing-canvas) has been asked before, however it doesn't seem to provide a correct answer.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An html canvas is just a bunch of pixels.

You can convert those pixels into an image and then use that image as the source for a Kinetic.Image.

```
// create an image from the existing canvas

var canvas2Image=new Image();
canvas2Image.onload=function(){

    // create a Kinetic.Image using that image

    var kImage=new Kinetic.Image({
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width:canvas2Image.width,
        height:canvas2Image.height,
        image:canvas2Image
    });

}
canvas2Image.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: I am trying to get kinetic to use an existing canvas as its stage, not create a kinetic image object of another canvas. I want kinetic to be able to apply a kinetic layer to a canvas that I create, not one that it does via an instantiation of `Kinetic.Stage`

Comment: Understood...plugging an existing html canvas into Kinetic is not possible--apples vs oranges.  However, "pixels are pixels--nothing more".  Since html canvas is just pixels you can use those pixels to easily populate a Kinetic.Image.  If you're doing something dynamic with your html canvas, just (1) var kImage=Kinetic.Image and whenever the html canvas updates do (2) kImage.setImage(canvas2Image).  And if you've already created "smart objects" for your html canvas, your task is to port those JS objects into Kinetic objects.  Cheers!

Comment: An additional thought: The Kinetic.Shape gives you a blank canvas to work with.  You can use the usual context commands to draw on that canvas.  So you can grab whatever you're doing on your html canvas and easily do the same thing on a Kinetic.Shape: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/ (Warning: some limitations apply to this canvas/context that Kinetic.Shape gives you.  They are mostly-full-featured wrappers around an actual html canvas+context.  You can get the actual context using this.getContext()._context;